# Android: launching flash app as a screensaver

Tags: android, screensaver

i am new to android development and had question regarding custom screen saver. 
 The requirement is for a tablet which will always be plugged in so battery life wouldn't be
 an issue. The required app should behave as a screensaver in that during inactivity, the tablet should launch this app which contains a flash file that displays a series of images and video. When activity is resumed then the tablet takes the user back to the program they were using.

Can this be done via an app without requiring any hacks?

cheers,

abhi

Answer (score 0):

There is no concept of a "screensaver" in Android.

There is the lock screen, which can be modified via custom firmware, though AFAIK it is implemented in Java as part of the OS and therefore could not be replaced via a Flash APK.

Comment: thanks for your response. I am still confused and I hope you can shed some light. I did a quick search on google for screensaver apps for android and found the following link : http://www.androidzoom.com/android_applications/screensavers+for   some of the apps mentioned there seem to work when the screen times out i.e. when the lock key is enabled. This would suggest that apps can produce screensaver effect without custom firmware. Or have I failed to notice something obvious in these apps.  thanks

Comment: @amthekkel: Developers are welcome to say whatever they want about what their apps do, and many are liars. Some of those are home screen replacements that have you disable the Android lock screen, where they then provide their own lock-style capability. Some of them exploit security loopholes, the way malware does. However, all can be trivially bypassed unless they are part of the firmware. If you are truly working on a tablet, then you are truly working with firmware, and you can do things the right way.